# Form input with an associated label

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, webstorm, texttemplate

I'm doing a todo list on backbone by example. But I have an error when I'm using text/template. An error is - **Tag start is not closed**. :

```
<script type="text/template" id="item-template">
    <div class="view">
        <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" (error) <%= completed ? 'checked' : '' %>>
        <label><%- title %></label>
        <button class="destroy"></button>
    </div>
    <input class="edit" value="<%- title %>">
</script>
```

Comment: I edit my question, there is my full code of template...

Comment: WebStorm is giving me this error before this string <%= completed ? 'checked' : '' %> . An error is  - Tag start is not closed

Comment: WebStorm probably doesn't understand the template language.. does it work when running in the browser?

Comment: What template language is that? Have you tried installing plugin that supports it (if there is one, of course)?

Comment: It doesnt work in the browser. This template should display individual todo items such as (completed, active). But they dont work... I didnt try to install plugins.